# Lazy loading module with APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

We have an application where we are lazy loading modules via router. We need to load a some resources before the app module starts, but we don't want to use resolve on router. That's why we are trying to create some provider factory (APP_INITIALIZER) to load some data from server and then use it in components in that lazy loaded module. So every module will have some different settings like translations and so on...

I created a plunker for showcase.
https://embed.plnkr.co/uBK23O5cA7QGwlvmbi73/
If you click on lazy it should wait 10 seconds to load the module but its not happening.

We are using angular 2.0.0 version. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I think `APP_INITIALIZE` is used only for Application level.

Comment: Possible you need to use something like this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: Yes you are right, but I don't want to make this things on router. I need that every module pack his things in his level and not on level upper in router settings.

Comment: Yes I got it now. I will use resolve on router in the submodule. There is a blank route. `{ path: '', component: FileSharingComponent, **resolve: ...**
        children: [
            {path: '', redirectTo: 'cloud-service/internal-storage', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'cloud-service/:cloudServiceID', component: ListOutletComponent, children: childRoutes }
        ]
    }` thank you for your advices @yurzui

Comment: I have spent a whole day looking for a solution to the same problem, and it seems that `resolve` suits best to solve that kind of issues :)

Comment: @RomanKora What if the user copy pastes a link to a child route in the address bar? Will the resolver of the parent route still be called?

Comment: @S.Robijns yes it will