# Angular2 - asynchronous dependency injection

Tags: angular, asynchronous, dependency-injection

I use Angular2 v2.2.3

I've created common module with forRoot() function, like this:

```
    ...
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: CommonsModule,
        providers: [
            SomeOtherDependency,
            {
                provide: ConfigService,
                useFactory: ConfigFactory,
                deps: [Http]
            }                
        ]
    };
```

Here is my ConfigFactory:

```
export function ConfigFactory(http:Http):Promise<ConfigService> {    
    return http.get('confg/config.json').map(r => {
        return new ConfigService(r);
    }).toPromise();
}
```

I've tried to return Promise and Observable as well.

SomeOtherDependency defined in providers requires ConfigService. The problem is that Angular does not inject value resolved by promise but promise itself.

How can I force angular to wait until promise is resolved with proper dependency and only then inject it to other dependencies?

I've tried different approaches and always injected value is promise or observable. Just like the iniector ignores what type factory returned. I need to load some json files before whole application starts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Services consuming others services before call a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127741/angular-2-services-consuming-others-services-before-call-a-method)

Comment: Check out also comments to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522938/lazy-loading-module-with-app-initializer?noredirect=1#comment68288686_40522938

Comment: I've seen this topics before I asked. They does not work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a problem.

I was returning a promise from my factory when I needed to return function instead. Also I missed "multi" argument from provider section. Here is updated factory which works with APP_INITIALIZER:

```
export function ConfigFactory(config:ConfigService, http:Http):Function {
    return () => config.load(http);
}
```

And in module:

```
providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: ConfigFactory,
        deps: [ConfigService, Http],
        multi: true
    },
]
```

Comment: How can i use this value on another component ? Please send an example using plnkr.co

Comment: Use it like always: constructor(private configService:ConfigService) {}. I'll be injected without problems.