# Angular cancels HttpRequest send from APP_INITIALIZER after implementing Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, initialization, lazy-loading

I work on an Angular (currently v7) application which is using the `APP_INITIALIZER` to check if the user is logged in. The code is pretty straight-forward, I add the `APP_INITIALIZER`

```
@NgModule({
...,
providers: [
  ...,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: CheckLoginFactory,
    deps: [Initialization, AuthService, ObservableState],
    multi: true
  }
]
```

using this factory:

```
export function CheckLoginFactory(
  init: any,
  auth: AuthService,
  oss: ObservableState
) {
  const confirmLogin = auth
    .confirmLogin()
    .pipe(catchError(val => of(undefined)));

  return () => confirmLogin.toPromise();
}
```

and the `confirmLogin`-function checks whether the user is logged in

```
confirmLogin(): Observable<User> {
  return this.get('authentication/login').pipe(
    map(response => plainToClass(User, response as Object))
  );
}
```

So far so simple, this code has been working for the last year. Now I restructured the app and implemented lazy loading for all subpages of the app and now this code does not work anymore. The http-request send from `confirmLogin` always shows up as `canceled` in the dev-tools and the factory runs into the `.pipe(catchError(val => of(undefined)));`.

Is there anything that is different on how Angular handles the `APP_INITIALIZER` in apps using / not using lazy loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by cleaning up the code. It's still not clear to me, what fixed it though. Apparently some of the additional dependencies broke the code ... So all I did was cleaning up the `APP_INITIALIZER` section in the providers section to just one dependency:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: CheckLoginFactory,
  deps: [AuthService],
  multi: true
}
```

Angular apparently automatically knows which child-dependencies `AuthService` has, so they don't need to be specified explicitly again here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you lazy loading modules? If so, you have to make sure to provide the initializer in each module. This question answers the question nicely.

[Angular Does APP_INITIALIZER work inside of lazy loaded modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783765/angular-does-app-initializer-work-inside-of-lazy-loaded-modules)

Comment: Yes I am lazy loading modules, but if I understand the linked answer correctly I do _not_ have to supply the initializer in each module, but what it says is, that it will be loaded from the main.module before the lazy loaded modules are loaded. The function is executed, but then somehow cancels the http-request. The problem is not, that it does not fire at all.

Comment: @tommueller Sorry for the late reply. How does it cancel the http-request? Do you have an interceptor somewhere in your code? Or do you destroy the view before the request is done?

Comment: That is exactly what I do not know :)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it myself now. See my answer if you are interested!